# A positive real valued symetric matrix. Then A has only positive (not negative) Eigenvalues. determine if this is true for the following Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 3&\sqrt{2}&\sqrt{6} \\ \sqrt{2}&1&\sqrt{3} \\ \sqrt{6}&\sqrt{3}&4\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Hi im suppose to find Eigenvalues and eigen vectors for this Problem but when i find the det(A-xI) i get a complicated polynomial with imaginary numbers as roots. and then when i try to solve for the eigen vectors i get the null vector which i think is not allowed. Any help and constructive criticism is welcomed. By the way is there another simpler way to find eigen values? thanks

Comment: if anyone could help me find the eigen vectors that would be great. i have the first one for x=1 but with the other eigen vectors ist just getting confusing

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

You may be having some errors in your calculations,
the eigenvalues are $1$ and $\frac{7\pm 3 \sqrt{5}}{2}$, all positive. Getting eigenvectors is not that hard either.

Comment: i dont unerstand how you have that answer. do you not get ((x^2) -7x+23)(x-1)

Comment: i solved for det using sarrus rule

Comment: never mind i see what i did wrong thank you